# Excel VBA > update date to +1 hour when between 2 dates

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have 2 columns on dates, lets say A1:A100 & B2:B200 that may fall in between 2 dates ( in this case its the British Summer time range )

Can you help with a sub to update the range of cells with an extra hour if they fall between those 2 dates)

thanks
James

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with **their** code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your request you don't need a VBA function for this. You can do it just formulas.

Here's the formula to write and related excel sheet (in the picture the formula is different because I'm using Excel in Italian language):

```
=IF(AND($A$2<D7;D7<$B$2);D7+1/24;D7)
```

[image: excel sheet with formula]